# Background position animation is not working smoothly

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-animations

Hi I have some image as follows:

[image: smily]

which has some animation from left to right then bottom then left to right and so on.

> Image dimension `600 X 738` is and no and as number of squire is `5x5`.
>   I wrote css as follows to implement requirement:

```css
.cute_angry_steam_coming_out_of_face {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 52px;
  padding: 2px 2px 8px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 148px;
  animation: cute_happy_smiling_face 0 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQIqY.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 960px 785px;
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

@keyframes cute_happy_smiling_face {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  3% {
    background-position: 120px 0px;
  }
  6% {
    background-position: 240px 0px;
  }
  8% {
    background-position: 360px 0px;
  }
  11% {
    background-position: 480px 0px;
  }
  14% {
    background-position: 600px 0px;
  }
  17% {
    background-position: 0px 148px;
  }
  19% {
    background-position: 120px 148px;
  }
  22% {
    background-position: 240px 148px;
  }
  25% {
    background-position: 360px 148px;
  }
  28% {
    background-position: 480px 148px;
  }
  31% {
    background-position: 600px 148px;
  }
  33% {
    background-position: 0px 295px;
  }
  36% {
    background-position: 120px 295px;
  }
  39% {
    background-position: 240px 295px;
  }
  42% {
    background-position: 360px 295px;
  }
  44% {
    background-position: 480px 295px;
  }
  47% {
    background-position: 600px 295px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 0px 443px;
  }
  53% {
    background-position: 120px 443px;
  }
  56% {
    background-position: 240px 443px;
  }
  58% {
    background-position: 360px 443px;
  }
  61% {
    background-position: 480px 443px;
  }
  64% {
    background-position: 600px 443px;
  }
  67% {
    background-position: 0px 590px;
  }
  69% {
    background-position: 120px 590px;
  }
  72% {
    background-position: 240px 590px;
  }
  75% {
    background-position: 360px 590px;
  }
  78% {
    background-position: 480px 590px;
  }
  81% {
    background-position: 600px 590px;
  }
  83% {
    background-position: 0px 738px;
  }
  86% {
    background-position: 120px 738px;
  }
  89% {
    background-position: 240px 738px;
  }
  92% {
    background-position: 360px 738px;
  }
  94% {
    background-position: 480px 738px;
  }
  97% {
    background-position: 600px 738px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cute_angry_steam_coming_out_of_face"></div>
```

> But it is not animating smoothly till end. What I want with every picture it should hold for a second and position should change to next as fast it can with looping infinitely.
>
> At the end animation will look like following

[Animation Video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1drTy-1Af6zC_6n06m-XkYrhjwn0lVE3U)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it easier you can consider CSS variables and the trick is to use **negative** values for the position based on the width height.

You have 5 rows and 5 columns and 22 images so you split the animation into 22 states (`100/22 = 4.54`). On each state we increment a variable from `0` to `4` on the x-axis and when we reach `4` we reset to `0` and we increment the y-axis.

You can also easily adjust the dimension by simply changing the CSS variables so you don't need to know the width/height of the image, you only need to know the number of rows and columns

```css
.cute_angry_steam_coming_out_of_face {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  --w:120px;
  --h:148px;
  width: var(--w);
  height: var(--h);
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQIqY.png');
  background-size: calc(5*var(--w)) calc(5*var(--h));
  animation: cute_happy_smiling_face 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes cute_happy_smiling_face {
  0%,4.54% {
    background-position: calc(0*var(--w)) calc(0*var(--h));
  }
  4.55%,9.09% {
    background-position: calc(-1*var(--w)) calc(0*var(--h));
  }
  9.10%,13.63% {
    background-position: calc(-2*var(--w)) calc(0*var(--h));
  }
  13.64%,18.18% {
    background-position: calc(-3*var(--w)) calc(0*var(--h));
  }
  18.19%,22.72% {
    background-position: calc(-4*var(--w)) calc(0*var(--h));
  }
  22.73%,27.27% {
    background-position: calc(0*var(--w)) calc(-1*var(--h));
  }
  27.28%,31.81% {
    background-position: calc(-1*var(--w)) calc(-1*var(--h));
  }
  31.82%,36.36% {
    background-position: calc(-2*var(--w)) calc(-1*var(--h));
  }
  36.37%,40.90% {
    background-position: calc(-3*var(--w)) calc(-1*var(--h));
  }
  40.91%,45.45% {
    background-position: calc(-4*var(--w)) calc(-1*var(--h));
  }
  45.46%,50% {
    background-position: calc(0*var(--w)) calc(-2*var(--h));
  }
  50.01%,54.54% {
    background-position: calc(-1*var(--w)) calc(-2*var(--h));
  }
  54.55%,59.09% {
    background-position: calc(-2*var(--w)) calc(-2*var(--h));
  }
  59.10%,63.63% {
    background-position: calc(-3*var(--w)) calc(-2*var(--h));
  }
  63.64%,68.18% {
    background-position: calc(-4*var(--w)) calc(-2*var(--h));
  }
  68.19%,72.72% {
    background-position: calc(0*var(--w)) calc(-3*var(--h));
  }
  72.73%,77.27% {
    background-position: calc(-1*var(--w)) calc(-3*var(--h));
  }
  77.28%,81.81% {
    background-position: calc(-2*var(--w)) calc(-3*var(--h));
  }
  81.82%,86.36% {
    background-position: calc(-3*var(--w)) calc(-3*var(--h));
  }
  86.37%,90.9% {
    background-position: calc(-4*var(--w)) calc(-3*var(--h));
  }
  90.91%,95.45% {
    background-position: calc(0*var(--w)) calc(-4*var(--h));
  }
  95.46%,100% {
    background-position: calc(-1*var(--w)) calc(-4*var(--h));
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="cute_angry_steam_coming_out_of_face"></div>


<div class="cute_angry_steam_coming_out_of_face" style="--w:100px;--h:120px"></div>

<div class="cute_angry_steam_coming_out_of_face" style="--w:50px;--h:80px"></div>
```

Another intresting idea (which I recommend) with less of code is to animate each position alone and use `steps()`. This will make the code easier. The only drawback is that you will see the 3 empty slots. This method is perfect if you have exactly 5x5 images (25) and not only 22.

```css
.cute_angry_steam_coming_out_of_face {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  --w:120px;
  --h:148px;
  width: var(--w);
  height: var(--h);
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQIqY.png');
  background-size: calc(5*var(--w)) calc(5*var(--h));
  animation-name:     smiling_face-x, smiling_face-y; 
  animation-duration: 0.5s            ,2.5s; /* 2.5 = 5 x 0.5 */
  animation-timing-function:steps(5);
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@keyframes smiling_face-x {
  100% {
    background-position-x: calc(-5*var(--w));
  }
}
@keyframes smiling_face-y {
  100% {
    background-position-y: calc(-5*var(--h));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cute_angry_steam_coming_out_of_face"></div>


<div class="cute_angry_steam_coming_out_of_face" style="--w:100px;--h:120px"></div>

<div class="cute_angry_steam_coming_out_of_face" style="--w:50px;--h:80px"></div>
```

Here is a more generic code consider `NxM` image:

```css
.cute_angry_steam_coming_out_of_face {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  --w:120px;
  --h:148px;
  --n:3; /* number of rows     */
  --m:5; /* number of columns */
  --d:2s; /*duration*/
  width: var(--w);
  height: var(--h);
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2n58.png');
  background-size: calc(var(--m)*var(--w)) calc(var(--n)*var(--h));
  animation-name:     smiling_face-x, smiling_face-y; 
  animation-duration: calc(var(--d)/var(--n)),var(--d);
  animation-timing-function:steps(var(--m)),steps(var(--n));
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@keyframes smiling_face-x {
  100% {
    background-position-x: calc(-1*var(--m)*var(--w));
  }
}
@keyframes smiling_face-y {
  100% {
    background-position-y: calc(-1*var(--n)*var(--h));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cute_angry_steam_coming_out_of_face"></div>


<div class="cute_angry_steam_coming_out_of_face" style="--w:100px;--h:120px"></div>

<div class="cute_angry_steam_coming_out_of_face" style="--w:50px;--h:80px"></div>
```

Comment: does it support all browser..?

Comment: @AkhileshKumar what exactly?

Comment: The css variable you had given are they supported in all major browser.?

Comment: @AkhileshKumar yes they are: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables only IE will fail but this is not a surprise

Comment: It is not handling `M x N` size with empty slots. How to handle them? Because I have some `M x M` and `M x N` and generating css dynamically. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @AkhileshKumar are you correctly changing the code? you need to change the `5` here with your new `N` and `M`

Comment: fields:

`animation-duration: 0.5s            ,2.5s; /* 2.5 = 5 x 0.5 */
  animation-timing-function:steps(5); `
   will it work with `M x N`
What will be value in case of MxN

Comment: @AkhileshKumar check the update, I added a more generic code with N and M

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*{"dim":[600,738], "n":[5, 5]}*/
.cute_angry_steam_coming_out_of_face {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 52px;
  padding: 2px 2px 8px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  animation: cute_happy_smiling_face 0 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQIqY.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 960px 785px;
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
@keyframes cute_happy_smiling_face {
  0% {background-position:0px 0px;}
  50% {background-position:0px 200px;}
  75% {background-position:200px 200px;}
  100% {background-position:300px 500px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cute_angry_steam_coming_out_of_face" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this, hope it'll help.

Comment: animation has to be descrete

Comment: each images should show equivalent to discrete from left to right and down

Comment: Check now if you're looking for something like this or show me an example so may i can help

Comment: It has to be like this https://drive.google.com/open?id=1drTy-1Af6zC_6n06m-XkYrhjwn0lVE3U